# new user from text file script

Tags: scripts

Hello guys im new in ubuntu,so i have an assigment to make a script that makes new user from text file.i have some problems and cant extract from text.may u help me?thanks a lot.
Here's my code:

```
while  [ $Username! = "" ]
        do
        Username=`grep "Username00$num" $Path | cut -f2 -d:`  #Username   
num=$(($num+1))
        Password=`grep "Password" $Path | cut -f2 -d:`      
        Group=`grep "Group" $Path |cut -f2 -d:`              #Group   

        groupadd $Group
```

the problem is on first line,i cant paste the whole code cause is 160 lines.

Comment: You could use [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) for the full script... and Adding the error it gives would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

The main problem in your first line is the incorrect whitespace - the "not equal" needs to be a single operator like `!=` rather than `! =`, and the `!` needs to be separated from the variable preceding it. You should also quote the variable in any string comparisons, in case it contains whitespace

```
while  [ "$Username" != "" ]
```

If you post a sample of the text file there's almost certainly a better way to read the username / password / group fields (instead of using lots of `grep` and `cut` commands).

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem (homework)

I need to create new users using details taken from a text file, and I can only use shellscripting and awk.

The text file got this format

user:1111:homedir

the field separator is ":"

I would than any help